# Не загружается список листов в переменную из обьекта board из py-trello

Tags: python, trello

Я написал код:

```
class DataFromTrello():
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = TrelloClient(api_key="...",api_secret="...",token="...")                 
         self.boards = self.client.list_boards(board_filter='starred')
        self.array = pd.DataFrame(np.object, index=[], columns=[])      
    def get_cards_from_board(self, board):
        t = []
        lists = board.list_lists(self)
        for l in lists:
            cards = l.list_cards(self)
            for c in cards:
                t.append(c)
        return t
```

и так далее. Но PyCharm выдает ошибку в строке `lists = board.list_lists(self)`:

> ```
> AttributeError: module 'trello.board' has no attribute 'list_lists'
> ```

Как исправить ошибку?

Comment: вы передали в метод `get_cards_from_board` модуль `trello.board` вместо объекта типа `trello.board.Board`

Comment: Спасибо godva за быструю реакцию и помощь. Я написал lists = board.Board.list_lists(self) но получил ошибку: "AttributeError: 'DataFromTrello' object has no attribute 'get_lists'" Как можно исправить?

Comment: Все ок. Ошибка исправлена. Код работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильный код:

```
class DataFromTrello():
def __init__(self):
    self.client = TrelloClient(api_key="...", api_secret="...",token="...")                                        
    self.boards = self.client.list_boards(board_filter='starred')
    self.array = pd.DataFrame(np.object, index=[], columns=[])

def cards_from_board(self, board):
    print(type(board))
    assert isinstance(board, object)
    t = []
    lists = board.list_lists()
    for l in lists:
        if l.name == 'Done':
            cards = l.list_cards()
            for c in cards:
               t.append(c)
    return t
```

Только вот класс DataFromTrello статическим получается...